# something wrong when installing opencv3.4.1 on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: opencv, makefile, ros, ubuntu-20.04

I followed the tutorial to install opencv3.4.1 on Ubuntu20.04. After executing the **make** command, I encountered an error at 99% progress as shown in the picture. I could not find a solution online, so I would like to ask how to solve this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dyph.jpg)
The tutorial link is as follows:https://github.com/thinkexist1989/ROS-Academy-for-Beginners/blob/noetic/orbslam2_demo/OpenCV%203.4.1%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85.md I searched online for some tutorials similar to this issue, but did not find an exact solution.